# Ramifications of changing the Web Service Identity for SQL Reporting Services 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, configuration, reporting-services

Due to requirements of a piece of software I am planning on installing, I have to change the Identity the IIS Application Pool for SQL Reporting Services 2005 is running under.  Unfortunately, I am unable to find any information of the ramifications of doing so.

I was hoping someone here would be able to point me to some information on the subject.

If you need more information, just ask and I will post what I can.

SQL Reporting Services is currently running on a dedicated server.
The application pool is currently using "NT Authority\NetworkService" and will need to be changed to use an Active Directory domain account.
The Application I am installing is running distributed across several servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it shouldn't be a problem as the SSRS service connects to the database with the accounts specified via the SSRS configuration utility.